# To find a Differential equations when auxilary diff eq have known roots

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

The roots of an auxiliary equation are $m_1=4 , m_2=m_3=-5$. How do I find the corresponding differential equation?

Comment: Basically the same way you find a polynomial with given roots and multiplicities thereof.

Answer (score 1):

Since the roots of the auxiliary equation are $~m_1=4 , m_2=m_3=-5~$, so the auxiliary equation can be written as $$(m-4)(m+5)(m+5)=0\implies m^3+6m^2-15m-100=0$$
So the differential equation is $$ (D^3+6D^2-15D-100)y=0$$
$$\implies  \frac{d^3y}{dx^3}+6\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}-15\frac{dy}{dx}-100y=0$$